# How to reduce memory usage, most probably caused by Docker?

Tags: windows-10, performance, docker, memory-management, resource-monitor

My PC is using an enormous amount of memory:
Hereby a screenshot of the resource monitor:

[image]

The "vmmem" process is caused by Docker, but the amount of containers is not that high: 212, 160, 516 and 29Mb, and a 1Gb and 1.3Gb, so alltogether the total amount of RAM is not even 4Gb.

So, where is that memory usage of 7.4-8Gb coming from and how can I reduce this (my computer is becoming very slowly because of swapping reasons)?

Comment: Maybe a WSL 2 memory limit could help.

Comment: @DanielB: Thanks: that memory limit is handled in the `C:\Users\UserName\.wslconfig` file and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Desktop runs in a VM, and that memory is assigned to the VM. The VM doesn't share memory with the host and return it when it's unused like a container process would do. To adjust this value, go into the settings of Docker Desktop and change the assigned resources.

More details of this are in Docker's documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/windows/#resources

Comment: Docker Desktop will prefer using WSL over a Hyper-V VM. (Technically there's an underlying VM in there too, but it's irrelevant.) In the WSL mode resource controls won't be available. Limits will have to be set externally for the entire WSL.